# Getting started with OpenID

Tags: java, openid

I'm looking to integrate OpenID into my website, but I need a tutorial to help me get going.

You can assume I have a good programming knowledge when making a recommendation :)

Comment: Please tag which programming language you are using. There are lots of libraries that do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Most of my framework is in Java, but I'm just trying to understand the technology in general

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An excellent tutorial that explains how OpenID works can be found here:

[Enterprise Java: Using OpenID](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=OpenID)

and shows you how to implement it using OpenID4Java (maintained on code.google.com)

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do, use an existing library. Few have read through the specs and lived to tell the tale.

Answer (score 0):

[openid](http://openid.net/)

They have a handy little section on adding it to your website.